# What tests to analyze the following hypotheses with nominal data?

Tags: statistical-significance, spss, cross-validation, dataset, computational-statistics

I have a set of questionnaire data to analyze the working culture for respondents. (There are four existing cultures; a,b,c and d)

Variables including Gender, Organization, Public/Private Sector, Company Size and Culture.

I would like to test the following hypotheses:

1. Among public sector, culture B is dominant .
2. Any type of culture is presented in Private Sector.
3. Culture B is dominant in company with size over 1000 employees.

These hypotheses can all be easily shown in charts. However, since the variables are all nominal and ordinal data, I do not have any idea on which statistical test to apply in SPSS.

I would be much appreciate if anyone can discuss with me and give me an idea on it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "dominant" mean here? Do you hypothesize that culture X is the modal choice, or that it is >50%? What does "any type... is presented" mean, that it happens at least once in the population (concretely, in your dataset)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes, "dominant" means culture X is > certain % say 50%. And yes, "any type is presented" means it happens at least once in the dataset

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to estimate a multinomial logit model, assuming that your "culture variables" can actually be conceptualized as a single nominal variable with four categories.

The multinomial logit model is really just a series of binary logit models for every pairwise comparison with your reference group. For example, if your reference group is culture a, then the multinomial model would give you a-b, a-c, and a-d comparisons across a set of predictors. So you would simply include your non-culture variables as predictors (i.e., those variables you are using to explain variation in culture use) and see if your nulls hold or can be rejected.

The problem with multinomial models, though is that the interpretation of coefficients is always constrained by the particular DV category comparison being made--i.e., the coefficients are always relative to a reference category. Some adjusted predictions and/or marginal effects can help you out here. There are also some commands in Stata that allow you to make every pairwise DV category contrast, but I am not sure about SPSS.